# json schema for property that is not decided

Tags: jsonschema

I have a HTTP response body json object, of which the name of the top level property (`${id}`) is changing in each response. I am wondering how to describe it in json schema?

```
{
    "${id}": {
        "option": {
            "name": "value"
        }
     }
}
```

It could be:

```
{
    "12874349: {
        "option": {
            "name": "value"
        }
     }
}
```

or

```
{
    "12874349: {
        "option": {
            "name": "value"
        }
     },
    "12874350: {
        "option": {
            "name": "value"
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use `additionalProperties`:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "option": {...}
        }
    }
}
```

or `patternProperties`:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        "^[1-9][0-9]*$": {  // regex for a positive integer
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "option": {...}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You don't mention it in your question, but if you wanted to place limits on the number of top-level properties, you can use `minProperties`/`maxProperties`, e.g.:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "minProperties": 1,  // at least one property
    "maxProperties": 5,  // no more than five at a time
    "patternProperties": {
        "^[1-9][0-9]*$": {...}
    }
}
```